# How to create child route with :id parameter in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the following routeConfig with this routes working correctly:

```
export const routeConfig: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'use-cases', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'use-cases', component: UseCasesComponent},
    {path: 'add', component: AddComponent},
    {path: '**', redirectTo: 'use-cases'},
];
```

how to add a route for `use-cases/:id`?

I have tried this:

```
{path: 'use-cases', component: UseCasesComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '/:id',
            component: UseCaseComponent,
        }
    ]
},
```

but it gives me error

EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.bundle.js:15073:32)
    at http://localhost:3000/polyfills.bundle.js:15050:14
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.bundle.js:14837:27)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:7133:42)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.bundle.js:14836:33)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.bundle.js:14719:44)
    at http://localhost:3000/polyfills.bundle.js:15107:58
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.bundle.js:14870:36)
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't add leading slashes to `path: '...'`

```
 path: '/:id'
```

should be

```
 path: ':id'
```

Comment: I changed it like you recommended but still getting exact same error :(

Comment: Can you create a Plunker that allows to reproduce. Please use the Angular2 TS Plunker template provide by Plunker under the "new |v" button in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the slash before Id. Try this:

```
{
    path: 'use-cases', component: UseCasesComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: ':id',
            component: UseCaseComponent,
        }
    ]
},
```

It works!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add children in first path

```
export const routeConfig: Routes = [
   {path: '', redirectTo: 'use-cases', pathMatch: 'full', children:   [{path: ':id', component: UseCaseComponent}]},
   {path: 'use-cases', component: UseCasesComponent},
   {path: 'add', component: AddComponent},
   {path: '**', redirectTo: 'use-cases'},
];
```

I hope that helps.