# Can Angular Child Routes begin with a parameter?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Angular child route that starts with a parameter does not work:

I've defined a route array in a module where the path starts with a parameter (:organisationName)

Within that path I've defined a child whose path also starts with a parameter (:groupName)

However this does not work. I've used route debugging (enableTracing: true) and added other debugging code. I can see that the component is identified, but it does not load. There are no errors in browser console.

```
const orgRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':organisationName', component: OrganisationComponent,
    children: [{ path: ':groupName', component: GroupComponent }]
  }
];
```

However, if I don't use the children property of the parent path, this does work

```
const orgRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: ':organisationName', component: OrganisationComponent },
  { path: ':organisationName/:groupName', component: GroupComponent },
];
```

So I have a workaround (which hopefully will help others), but it's not clear why the first method does not work (and others may be spending time like I have to resolve this).

I can't find reference to this specific case in the docs and the only SO question that references this indicates this should be possible (although author has a different error I'm not seeing) [How to create child route with :id parameter in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40288856/how-to-create-child-route-with-id-parameter-in-angular2)

Answer not found here: https://angular.io/guide/router

Angular Routing children with Parameters- http://www.mtutorial.com/angular-routing-children-with-parameters-activatedroute-and-get-route-params-child Example given uses my workaround without explanation

Angular Training Guide does not give an example where the child route begins with a parameter - https://angular-training-guide.rangle.io/routing/child_routes

Comment: child route expects <router-outlet></router-outlet> added in parent html file. Is it done?